# Which snapins do I need to run sql server powershell?

Tags: sql-server-2008, powershell, batch-file

what snapins or initializations do I need to run a sql server powershell script (using invoke-sqlcmd), as a batch file or windows scheduled task??

I have tried the following:

```
# mysqlscript.ps1
. "D:\Posh\init-sql.ps1"
invoke-sqlcmd .....
```

where init-sql.ps1 is the provider initialization as described by Microsoft (see [Adding the SQL Server Snap-ins to Windows PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281962.aspx)).

Then, I tried the following:

```
powershell.exe -noe "D:\Posh\mysqlscript.ps1"
```

What happens is just the opening of the powershell command prompt. I'm pretty sure that the invoke-sqlcmd is not executed.

Thanks
Emi

Comment: I'm sorry, but this monring I verified that invoke-sqlcmd works fine and I was only doing wrong tests. However, the solution below is a good alternative if someone needs to use invoke-sqlcmd only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is use invoke-sqlcmd you could use a very simple function in its place:

Copy the function invoke-sqlcmd2 into your script:

http://poshcode.org/2279

Comment: ok, thanks! I will try it and let you know! Not yet clear why the standard initialization does not work when executed as described in my question.

Comment: I've run into a few problems with the initialization script. First if you're on an x64 machine depending on whether the script is called form x86 or x64 PowerShell the script may not work as the against registry won't work. Easy enough to fix by remove the check. Second this does add-pssnapin which if you haven't run before needs to be run as administrator. Again easy to fix. My feeling though is if all you need is invoke-sqlcmd don't bother with SQL Server 2008/2008 R2 PowerShell snapins

Comment: Hello, I'have tried your script and it's working fine. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I went back to invoke-sqlcmd because now I need to pass parameters to the query, and your function does not support them :(. Are you going to extend it? Would it take much effort?

Comment: The parameters invoke-sqlcmd supports are kind of a wierd sqlcmd.exe style parameters. Not sure why you'd want to use them over straight PowerShell variables. For instance I can define a variable $a='smith' and a query "select * from authors where au_lname = '$a'"

Comment: When you have complex queries to execute, you find that's easier place them in external `.sql` scripts and this keeps your code cleaner. External file parametric queries can't take advantage of posh variables. That's why I think is a missing in your function.